# How to remove duplicate values From String Array

Tags: java

I am using the following code and this is giving me a duplicate values in every position of the array
So suggest me what to do

```
String sCurrentLine;
String username[] = new String[30];
String Arrival[] = new String[30];
String Departure[] = new String[30];
int var = 0, var2;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\Shubham Projects\\Input.txt"));

while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] information = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
    var2 = information.length + var;
    for (int i = var; i < var2; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        username[i] = information[0];
        Arrival[i] = information[1];
        Departure[i] = information[2];
        var++;
    }

}
for (int i = 0; i < username.length; i++)
    System.out.println(username[i] + " " + Arrival[i] + " " + Departure[i]);
```

Input:

> Jai 10:15 11:10
>   Jai 10:10 11:00
>   Veeru 10:10 11:00
>   Veeru 16:30 18:45
>   Jai 12:05 12:30
>   Veeru 12:30 13:25
>   Veeru 12:45 13:25
>   Jai 17:25 18:01

Output:

> Jai 10:15 11:10
>   Jai 10:15 11:10
>   Jai 10:15 11:10
>   Jai 10:10 11:00
>   Jai 10:10 11:00
>   Jai 10:10 11:00
>   Veeru 10:10 11:00
>   Veeru 10:10 11:00
>   Veeru 10:10 11:00
>   Veeru 16:30 18:45
>   Veeru 16:30 18:45
>   Veeru 16:30 18:45
>   Jai 12:05 12:30
>   Jai 12:05 12:30
>   Jai 12:05 12:30
>   Veeru 12:30 13:25
>   Veeru 12:30 13:25
>   Veeru 12:30 13:25
>   Veeru 12:45 13:25
>   Veeru 12:45 13:25
>   Veeru 12:45 13:25
>   Jai 17:25 18:01
>   Jai 17:25 18:01
>   Jai 17:25 18:01
>   null null null
>   null null null
>   null null null
>   null null null
>   null null null
>   null null null

Comment: Can you please show your `Input.txt` content ?

Comment: Jai 10:15 11:10
Jai 10:10 11:00
Veeru 10:10 11:00
Veeru 16:30 18:45
Jai 12:05 12:30
Veeru 12:30 13:25
Veeru 12:45 13:25
Jai 17:25 18:01

Comment: What is the problem then ?? Input and output matched right ?

Comment: No where you are checking the duplicates and also input & ouput got matched right?

Comment: Please check the post again, because by mistake I have uploaded the Input file in place of Output...
Now Can you give me the solution???
@Suresh ATTA

Comment: No Actually input and output is matched but there are lots of duplicate values are there in output array....
@Shriram

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Set` data structure which allows no duplicates.

Try:

```
    Set<String> resultSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(username));
```

`resultSet` will have unique Strings.

Comment: Good solution but can you tell, what is the issue with current code ?

Comment: The issue is the code is printing duplicate values in all the array that I used in the code

Answer (score 1):

Inner for loop is causing the issue because you're grabbing the information from every line three times.

```
var2 = information.length + var;
for (int i = var; i < var2; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    username[i] = information[0];
    Arrival[i] = information[1];
    Departure[i] = information[2];
    var++;
}
```

#### For example:

> Jai 10:15 11:10

When you read this line, var2 will evaluate to 3 (assuming var is 0). Now it'll run through the for loop three times, giving you your duplicate entries.

Shriram's solution will fix this issue and Amila's response will fix the issue of duplicate entries in the input file.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of set and print the result, because Set won't allow duplicates.

Use the below logic

```
int count = 0;
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] information = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
            // for (int i = 0; i < information.length; i++) {
            username[count] = information[0];
            Arrival[count] = information[1];
            Departure[count] = information[2];
            // }
            count++;
        }
```

After printing the output the remaining null values are nothing but you have initalized string array with 30. Make use of collection classes for dynamic array. Also i said make use of Set to avoid duplicated

Comment: Good solution but can you tell, what is the issue with current code ?